# React Native view is not 100% width

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, view, expo

I tried almost everything I could, why the `BarCodeScanner` view isn't full width?
It has what looks like 15-20px padding left and right, so there're white vertical stripes at the sides of it.
I'm testing this on a real device with Android 8

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class BarcodeScannerExample extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}>
          <BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
            style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, styles.container]}>
          </BarCodeScanner>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const qrSize = width * 0.9;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: width,
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BarcodeScannerExample} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `BarCodeScanner`'s camera always retains its aspect ratio (height/width). Your phone's screen (safe area) has a slightly different aspect ratio and therefore the camera doesn't fit perfectly.

You can remove the `absoluteFillObject` from `style` to fix this.

Comment: doesn't work, already tried but i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I think we can use the Camera component instead

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

 <Camera
                    onBarCodeScanned={canScan ? handleBarCodeScanned : undefined}
                    style={[{
                        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
                        height: Dimensions.get('screen').height
                    }, StyleSheet.absoluteFill]} >
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest you use the `Camera` component, `BarCodeScanner` has some issues occupying 100% width and/or, height in some cases.

Install `Camera` component using

```
expo install expo-camera
```

or

```
npm install expo-camera
```

Usage:

```
<Camera
                   onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? handleBarCodeScanned : undefined}
                   style={[{
                       width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
                       height: Dimensions.get('screen').height
                   }, StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]} >
```

You can further improvise the UI by having a transparent center area for scanning with translucent or darkened edges. 
E.g:

```
<Camera
                    onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? handleBarCodeScanned : undefined}
                    style={[{
                        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
                        height: Dimensions.get('screen').height
                    }, StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject]} >
        <View style={styles.layerTop} />
        <View style={styles.layerCenter}>
          <View style={styles.layerLeft} />
          <View style={styles.focused} />
          <View style={styles.layerRight} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.layerBottom} />
</Camera>
```

```
const opacity = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    
  },
  layerTop: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: opacity
  },
  layerCenter: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  layerLeft: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: opacity
  },
  focused: {
    flex: 6,
    
  },
  layerRight: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: opacity
  },
  layerBottom: {
    flex: 4,
    backgroundColor: opacity
  },
});
```

You can adjust the flex values of different style attributes (e.g: layerTop, layerLeft and so forth) to move the transparent view about the center.